# can we add watermark text within Microsoft office documents?

Tags: c#, .net, watermark, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

can we add watermark text within Microsoft office documents at time of downloading file from BLOB storage?

my analysis is in progress by using AIP - azure information protection.

Answer (score 1):

The MIP SDK doesn't support applying watermarks today. If you need to programmatically apply watermarks, you'd have to use COM interop with Office, or some other library to apply the watermark.

MIP SDK will apply a metadata property called ContentBits. When this is set, it informs the MIP-enabled consumer that it should apply the content marking upon open/save. In that scenario, the document itself won't have the watermark until opened in Office with the AIP client installed.